# Counting number of repeating fields using Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to count the number of fields added by user.

```
<div class="myzebra-repeatable-field">
  <input id="cred_form_3584_1_wpcf-ticket-student-name" class="myzebra-control myzebra-text myzebra-prime-name-wpcf-ticket-student-name" type="text" placeholder="" value="" name="wpcf-ticket-student-name[0]">
</div>
<div class="myzebra-repeatable-field" style="display: block;">
  <input id="cred_form_3584_1_wpcf-ticket-student-name_repeat_2" class="myzebra-control myzebra-text myzebra-prime-name-wpcf-ticket-student-name" type="text" placeholder="" value="" name="wpcf-ticket-student-name[2]" style="visibility: visible;">
  <a class="myzebra-remove-field" href="javascript:;">Remove</a>
</div>
<div class="myzebra-repeatable-field" style="display: block;">
  <input id="cred_form_3584_1_wpcf-ticket-student-name_repeat_3" class="myzebra-control myzebra-text myzebra-prime-name-wpcf-ticket-student-name" type="text" placeholder="" value="" name="wpcf-ticket-student-name[3]" style="visibility: visible;">
  <a class="myzebra-remove-field" href="javascript:;">Remove</a>
</div>
```

The first field is required(so there is no remove button), and the rest can be removed, therefore I need to know what I should do to count the number of fields in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply

```
var nb = $('.myzebra-repeatable-field').length - 1 ;
```

?

If you want to explicitely count the ones having the remove link, you can do

```
var nb = $('.myzebra-repeatable-field .myzebra-remove-field').length ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) and have a look at the length of the returned HTMLCollection:

```
var u = document.getElementsByClassName('myzebra-repeatable-field').length - 1;
```

Comment: I just tried, it returned -1. So think it doesn't work.. or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: @EmersonF: Nah, I was stupid. The dot `.` isn't part of the class name.